# Include library in Mac Project

Tags: macos

I have a Library project "Mobiledeviceaccess", if i build this project, i get libMobileDeviceAccess.a file in build/debug, How to use this library in MAC application Project. How to use this library class file?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .a file to the project in the same way that you would add a source file. You'll also need to add any relevant .h files for the library's public API.

Comment: I added the Mobiledeviceaccess.a file in my project.But i am not access the class. Library source:  https://bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess

Comment: Did you add the .h file(s) too ?

Comment: @Sezhian: you'll need to be more specific about what exactly "is not working properly" - please post actual error messages.

Comment: bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess where i got the source code, can you please use library in MAC application and tell me?

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't post any information about the errors you are getting. One thing though: did you add the MobileDevice framework to your project ? /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework

Comment: Error:<IOSurface/IOSurface.h>

Comment: Copy and paste the entire error message - it sounds like you have still not added all the required frameworks to your project though...