# Writing files to an iOS device from a MacOS app

Tags: cocoa, ios, macos

I'd like to be able to transfer files from a MacOS app to a connected iOS devices, so a related iOS app can open them - effectively replicating iTunes music functionality, but not for musc. Is this possible? I know you can set an iOS app to have file sharing enables so you can drop files into it with iTunes, but I'd prefer to do it in my own app.

Comment: A very similar question was already asked earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995026/how-to-save-files-onto-an-iphone

Answer (score 0):

This library came up in [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975540/include-library-in-mac-project/5975592) recently: https://bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess/ - I don't know anything about it but it sounds like it might do what you want ?

Comment: mobledeviceaccess does not let you do stuff via itunes. it usesna private framework that itunes installs but you still need to write all the sync side yourself. mobiledviceaccess (and ipodaccess from the same site) just copy the files for you.

Comment: @jeff: thanks for the clarification - sounds like it might still be useful though ?