# Is it possible to edit iOS files from a macOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have been trying to make a pair of apps, one for iOS and one for macOS, such that when the device is connected to the computer via USB you can edit the iOS app's documents from the mac app. Is that possible these days?

By the way, I am aware that this question was asked ten years ago, but I was hoping there would be a new answer now we have the Finder and Files for iOS rather than iTunes:
[Writing files to an iOS device from a MacOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997228/writing-files-to-an-ios-device-from-a-macos-app)

Comment: Only via iCloud as far as I know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483229/ios-pc-usb-communication Is a more recent version of the question. But I still think there's no better way to achieve this today.